# Shade out sector of circular image using css and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple circular image with an overlaying div of same dimensions and opacity of 0.4. I want to shade out only part of the image i.e. if I give it 100 degrees, I want it to show a circular section of the overlaying semi-transparent div of only 260 degrees. I have searched a lot but am not sure how to do this.

Here is the CSS for the overlaying div:

```
.shade {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    opacity: 0.4
}
```

Comment: With questions like these, it is helpful to attach a picture of what you're trying to achieve as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help out a ton.  It's for CSS3 Pie Charts, but maybe you can use some of these techniques to accomplish what you want with straight CSS.

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/07/designing-simple-pie-charts-with-css/